# MySQL DELETE takes many (40) seconds for few records while a SELECT of the same data is fast

Tags: mysql, database, performance, dml

Can any one give some insight on why **DELETE** statement taking more time to execute? We have not created any TRIGGER or CASCADE. We started to notice this issue when migrated to 8.0 from 5.5. Is it a issue related to 8.0 parameter tuning?

```
DELETE s FROM storefront s LEFT JOIN MASTER m  ON m.userid=s.userid WHERE m.userid IS NULL

9 row(s) affected 
Execution Time : 40.816 sec
Transfer Time  : 0.001 sec
Total Time     : 40.817 sec
```

At the same time, the **SELECT** statement takes a few mill seconds only.

```
SELECT s.userid FROM storefront s LEFT JOIN MASTER m  ON m.userid=s.userid WHERE m.userid IS NULL

Total Time     : 0.05 sec
```

Any help would be appreciated. We have a better server hardware with 16 GB of RAM.

Here is the PROFILING info for DELETE statement.

```
It is CPU_user(19.046875 seconds) and CPU_system(43.156250 seconds) taking most of the time out of the total execution time 50.24 seconds ....
```

Comment: Do you have any indices on either table?  Check `EXPLAIN` and see what is happening with both queries.

Comment: IFF the explains are the same, is there extreme lock contention? 40 seconds is a long time to delete 9 records, so unless they are a bajillion bytes in size..

Comment: Also, are there any CASCADE relationships or TRIGGERs? (This could require significantly different access..)

Comment: Please note the above two statements are same for EXPLAIN while  the later statement takes a few milliseconds only. I suspect about lock contention.

Comment: SELECT does not need to write something on disk whereas DELETE do.

Comment: @Akina, does 40 seconds seems to be fine to delete 9 records though from disk?

Comment: @user2864740 No trigger or cascade.

Comment: Records deletion may cause pages join. If you have not set innodb_file_per_table to ON then this join is performed in general tablespace. This may be really long... Or maybe there are some parallel operations, and write into undo file takes much time...

Comment: @Akina, We started to notice this issue when we  migrated form 5.5 to 8.0. Both tables are on myISAM. We have verified innodb_file_per_table as ON

Comment: In my experience, it's sometimes quicker to create a new table, retaining just the rows you want to keep, and the replace the old table.

Comment: Make sure to *update* the original post with this information.

Comment: @Strawberry - In my experience, I expect a database engine to be functionally useful. *40 seconds to delete 9 records* is not functionally useful for a RDBMS. If this was standard/expected behavior for MySQL, nobody would use it.

Comment: @user2864740 well said.

Comment: @user2864740 no it isn't. It's not about how many rows are affected. It's about how many rows are parsed. The alternative solution allows for the use of an inner join on an indexed column , which has the potential to be faster by an order or magnitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword is "MyISAM".  There are multiple reasons why it *might* be taking a long time.

(I assume both tables have an index on `userid`?  And the column definition is the same?)

- `SELECT` will be very fast because it will just use the index to find the userids in question.  0.05 seconds almost seems "too slow".
- MyISAM will do a table lock for the duration of the `DELETE`.
- MyISAM stores each row somewhere in the .MYD file.  The index is in the .MYI file, even for the Primary Key.
- I think a row is deleted by changing the initial byte of the row.  (Actually a byte whose sole purpose is to indicate deleted.
- In MyISAM, normally, a row is a contiguous stream of bytes in the .MYD.  Deletes and some Updates will leave holes in the .MYD.
- Inserts prefer to fill in the holes *first*, growing the file if that fails.  Note that a large row will be a linked list of pieces.  This leads, potentially, to slower and slower full-row Selects.
- Oracle plans to get rid of MyISAM.

Those do not really add up to an explanation for 40 seconds to delete only 9 rows. 
 Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN DELETE ...`; there may be details you left out or that I am falsely assuming.

Bottom Line:  Change to InnoDB, and these problems will go away.

Comment: changing to InnoDB worked like a charm. FYI, i would say, MYSQL treated MyISAM engine with more respect in  earlier versions than version 8.0. In version 5.5 we used MyISAM but never had such kind of noticeable issues

Comment: @CbproAds - Adding `FULLTEXT` and `SPATIAL` to InnoDB, plus the Data Dictionary, were the last big steps that Oracle did in order to deprecate MyISAM.  Now there is 'nothing' stopping them from getting rid of MyISAM.  I have not seen any other hints of actual sabotage (other than your mysterious perf problem).

Answer (score 0):

This is not the Answer, but it can help to find where so much time is spend. Use PROFILING

```
SET PROFILING=ON;
```

[Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-profile.html)

```
**sample**

mysql> SET PROFILING=ON;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from photons where photons >= 100;
+----+---------------------+---------+
| id | mytime              | photons |
+----+---------------------+---------+
|  1 | 2020-02-26 12:00:00 |     100 |
|  3 | 2020-02-26 12:01:00 |     100 |
|  4 | 2020-02-26 12:05:00 |     200 |
+----+---------------------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SHOW PROFILE ALL;
+----------------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+-----------------------+----------------------+-------------+
| Status               | Duration | CPU_user | CPU_system | Context_voluntary | Context_involuntary | Block_ops_in | Block_ops_out | Messages_sent | Messages_received | Page_faults_major | Page_faults_minor | Swaps | Source_function       | Source_file          | Source_line |
+----------------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+-----------------------+----------------------+-------------+
| starting             | 0.000130 | 0.000071 |   0.000057 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | NULL                  | NULL                 |        NULL |
| checking permissions | 0.002022 | 0.000127 |   0.000103 |                 2 |                   0 |          160 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 2 |                 1 |     0 | check_access          | sql_authorization.cc |         802 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000474 | 0.000040 |   0.000033 |                 1 |                   0 |            8 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 1 |                 1 |     0 | open_tables           | sql_base.cc          |        5715 |
| init                 | 0.000043 | 0.000023 |   0.000020 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | handle_query          | sql_select.cc        |         121 |
| System lock          | 0.000811 | 0.000046 |   0.000035 |                 2 |                   0 |           16 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 2 |                 2 |     0 | mysql_lock_tables     | lock.cc              |         323 |
| optimizing           | 0.000474 | 0.000027 |   0.000023 |                 1 |                   0 |            8 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 1 |                 1 |     0 | optimize              | sql_optimizer.cc     |         151 |
| statistics           | 0.000027 | 0.000014 |   0.000012 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | optimize              | sql_optimizer.cc     |         367 |
| preparing            | 0.000763 | 0.000044 |   0.000036 |                 2 |                   0 |           16 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 2 |                 2 |     0 | optimize              | sql_optimizer.cc     |         475 |
| executing            | 0.000007 | 0.000003 |   0.000003 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | exec                  | sql_executor.cc      |         119 |
| Sending data         | 0.000103 | 0.000057 |   0.000046 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | exec                  | sql_executor.cc      |         195 |
| end                  | 0.001408 | 0.000062 |   0.000050 |                 1 |                   0 |          248 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 1 |                 0 |     0 | handle_query          | sql_select.cc        |         199 |
| query end            | 0.000378 | 0.000029 |   0.000022 |                 1 |                   0 |            8 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 1 |                 1 |     0 | mysql_execute_command | sql_parse.cc         |        4946 |
| closing tables       | 0.000409 | 0.000022 |   0.000020 |                 1 |                   0 |            8 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 1 |                 1 |     0 | mysql_execute_command | sql_parse.cc         |        4998 |
| freeing items        | 0.000030 | 0.000017 |   0.000012 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | mysql_parse           | sql_parse.cc         |        5610 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000026 | 0.000014 |   0.000012 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | dispatch_command      | sql_parse.cc         |        1924 |
+----------------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+-----------------------+----------------------+-------------+
15 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: The SHOW PROFILE ALL; command returns zero rows for DELETE statement while for SELECT statement return 21 rows. I am  unable to see the rows of DELETE.

Comment: @Cbpro Ads - can you please post the results from profiling (select and delete)

Comment: I have added PROFILE for SELECT statements. Unfortunately no rows recturns for DELETE statement.

Comment: @Cbpro Ads - sorry can you put the tables and some sample data on http://sqlfiddle.com that i can test it

Comment: Finally i have got the PROFILING of DELETE statement. I can see this line is taking most of the time.                                                 It is CPU time(43.15 seconds).                                                                                                                                             executing 50.240687 19.046875 43.156250 \N \N \N \N \N \N \N \N \N SELECT_LEX_UNIT::ExecuteIterat sql_union.cc 1409

Comment: It is CPU_user(19.046875 seconds) and CPU_system(43.156250 seconds) taking most of the time out of the total execution time 50.24 seconds ....